# Resetting tableview scroll value from app delegate with TabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to call a method to reset the table view scroll value (to the top) by selecting a tab bar item in the appdelegate.m:

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    if (_appTabBarController.selectedIndex == 0) {

   HomeFeedVC *homeFeedVC = [[HomeFeedVC alloc]init];
   [homeFeedVC resetFeedValue];
  }
}
```

The method is being called from my HomeFeedVC.m:

```
    -(void)resetFeedValue
    {

        [_tableHomeFeed setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];

    }
```

The method runs all smoothly, although when I call that method, my `-dealloc` method is called in the same view controller:

```
    - (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]removeObserver:self name:@"uploadgif" object:nil];
    NSLog(@"dealloced called for HOME FEED VC...................");
    //    self.uploadProgressView=nil;
    //    infBtn = nil;
    //    [arrFeedData removeAllObjects],arrFeedData = nil;
    //    [self.progressBuffer removeAllObjects],self.progressBuffer = nil;
    //    self.session = nil;
    //    [self.tempDirectUrls removeAllObjects],self.tempDirectUrls = nil;
    //    [self.imageBuffer removeAllObjects],self.imageBuffer = nil;
}
```

I'm not sure what else to do... Should I implement a protocol? If so, how is that any different? I'm still successfully calling the method because if I place that method under any IBAction in my view, it successfully executes. Also my breakpoints go through my desired lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create a new `HomeFeedVC` in `-didSelectViewController` - get a reference to the existing one instead:

```
if (_appTabBarController.selectedIndex == 0)
{
  HomeFeedVC *homeFeedVC = (HomeFeedVC *)viewController;
  [homeFeedVC resetFeedValue];
}
```

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: I get this error message every time ====                                                                                                                            Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController resetFeedValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b0c7800'